# Is there a way to automatically create new material in all meshes in the model?

Tags: mesh, materials

is there a way to automatically create new material into every mesh of a model?

I have this issue with auto-rigging from Mixamo as it removes the existing materials when I download the rigged model. So I have to remake the materials again when importing the auto-rigged model back to Blender.

I don't mind if it assigns only the default Principled BSDF. I just need containers to put the shaders in when I import the model to Unity.

Comment: i) Do you have the blend with the materials pre-mixamo, and ii) are there more than 1 material per object, iii) if so, does the mesh still have materials  assigned to faces?

Comment: No, Each mesh has only material in it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly, but If you want to assign the same material to all objects then select all objects, click on the Object you want the materials to copy from (it gets highlighted in yellow) then press "Ctrl L" and choose Materials. All objects should share the same Materialdata then.
If you just have one model with different textures on it, go into edit mode select all vertices choose the one material you want to copy in the material bar on the right and press "assign" under the material options.

Comment: I'm sorry... I think I messed up my terms. What was actually asking is if there is a way to automatically create new materials on every single mesh in a model.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via python like this:

1. move all your objects which should have a new material in the collection named "Automatic" -> or change the python code to the name whatever you want
2. run the script

   ```
    import bpy


    def create_material(object):

        newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
        object.data.materials.append(newMat)

        newMat.use_nodes = True

        nodes = newMat.node_tree.nodes

        material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

        node_emission = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')

        node_emission.inputs[0].default_value = (1,0,0,1) 

        links = newMat.node_tree.links

        newLink = links.new(node_emission.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])

    index = bpy.data.collections.find('Automatic')
    coll = bpy.data.collections[index]

    for eachObject in coll.objects:

        if len(eachObject.data.materials) == 0:
            create_material(eachObject)
   ```

Comment: okay, so where do I run this script on?